# Git log branches splitting

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I've been doing some work on a project managed with git. At some point I created a branch with

```
git -b my-branch
```

did some work ,commited and pushed to the remote repo. Later, I merged with:

```
git checkout master
git merge my-branch
git push
```

But when i look at the graph with gitlab i do not see the branches splitting, just something like this

```
* * * * * * * 
            ^
            |
         my-branch
```

When i'd expect something like

```
* * * * * * *
    \-------^
            |
        my-branch
```

Why is this ?

Comment: I think the merge is a fast-forward merge. What you expected is a true merge. In your case, a fast-forward merge is the default behavior when it's possible. The commit pointed to by `master` is an ancestor of the commit pointed to by `my-branch`.You could add `--no-ff` (meaning *no fast-forward merge*) to enforce a true merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because of fast-forwarding. If Git doesn't need to do a merge, it won't. This happens when you merge a branch but have made no changes to its parent.

```
A - B - C - D - E [master]
                 \
                  F - G - H [feature]
```

In this repo there have been no changes to `master` since `feature` was branches. `master` is an ancestor of `feature`. That apparent branch between E and F isn't really there, the history is straight.

If you `git checkout master; git merge feature` it will "fast-forward" and you'll wind up with this.

```
                              [master]
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H [feature]
```

`master` is moved to the same commit as `feature`, no merge is done.

---

You can turn this off with `git merge --no-ff`. I recommend this when merging feature branches to avoid losing important information to understand the code. In the example above, there's no evidence that F, G, and H were done as a single feature. There's no link to the ticket discussing the feature.

Instead if we had `git checkout master; git merge --no-ff feature` this would force Git to merge even if it didn't have to.

```
A - B - C - D - E ---------- I [master]
                 \         /
                  F - G - H [feature]
```

I is the merge commit and you get a nice feature bubble.